# multiple expressions in ternary operator with react route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

Hey i want to set a session item on my route so i can use it on my authentication callback. So here i have a ternary operator and i check if the it is authenticated then i do something and if not i do two things.

it is not working. my question is how to do multiple things on ternary operator whether if it is true or false.

```
<Route path="/dashboard" render={(props) => (
          auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
              <whateverComp auth={auth} {...props} />
          ) : (
              <Redirect to="/log-in"/>
          ) ? // setter for page_name
              sessionStorage.setItem('page_name', 'dashboard'): null
      )}/>
```

My solution for this :

```
<Route path="/dashboard" render={(props) => {
        if (!auth.isAuthenticated()) {
          sessionStorage.setItem('page_name', 'dashboard');
          return <Redirect to="/log-in"/>;
        }
        else {
          return <Dashboard auth={auth} {...props} />;
        }
      }}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, the problem is that the ternary operator resolves into something that is then evaluated by whatever is on the *left* of the ternary.

For example

```
const x = condition
          ? result1
          : result2;
```

but if there's nothing on the left of the ternary, it doesn't do anything except side effects, which are done much more clearly with `if` statements. (you should also probably use `if`/`else` if your code is more complicated than can reasonably fit on a single line)

Maybe you wanted

```js
if (!auth.isAuthenticated()) return (
  <whateverComp auth={auth} {...props} />
);
sessionStorage.setItem('page_name', 'dashboard');
return (
  <Redirect to="/log-in"/>
);
```

Comment: Hey Certian thank you no i actually wanna do two things on the false result i want to set a session

Comment: Use an if statement for your code to be clear. (edited)

Answer (score 1):

```
choreDoor === 0 ? 
   (openDoor1 = botDoorPath,
    openDoor2 = beachDoorPath,
    openDoor3 = spaceDoorPath)
: choreDoor === 1 ? 
   (openDoor2 = botDoorPath,
    openDoor1 = beachDoorPath, 
    openDoor3 = spaceDoorPath) 
: choreDoor === 2 ?
   (openDoor3 = botDoorPath,
    openDoor1 = beachDoorPath, 
    openDoor2 = spaceDoorPath)
: false;
```

Solved my issue